# Unknown sequence with some values known

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that $n$ and $m$ are independant of eachother, and $f(n,m)$ is symmetrical. I can see different sequences within it, but is there a definite function $f: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ for all natural numbers, or does it have to be a composite function?

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n,m & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 &\cdots \\
2 &   & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36     \\
3 &   &   & 20 & 35 & 56 & 84 & 120     \\
4 &   &   &    & 70 & 126 & 210 & 330&\\
5 &   &   &    &    & 252 & 462  & 792  &\\
6 &   &   &    &    &     & 924  & 1716  & \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Please provide some context. Where are you getting these values from?

Comment: Also "definite functions" can be "composite functions", e.g., composed by the identity. It is not clear to me what you want to know here. There are infinitely many such functions with the given values for $1\le m,n\le 6$. The most convincing choice is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: I'm working on a problem where given two ordered arrays of length n and m, find all possible combinations of n and m where the order of elements in n maintain their relative order in the resulting array and so do the elements in m.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when $m \geq n$, the table entries are given by
$$
f(n,m) = \binom{m+1}{n},
$$
where $\binom nk$ denotes a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the solution I was looking for is indeed related to the binomial cefficent. The actual formula is: $ f(n,m) = \left( \array{n\\ m+n} \right) $, or when simplified $\displaystyle f(n,m) = \frac{(n+ m)!}{n!\ m!}$